# how to add text in top,left and bottom in funnel highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to give some text in top('test'), left('tests') and bottom('testy') of funnel highchart chart. I use **x,y** like this x: -500, y:100 but its not align properly on other browsers:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    title: {
        text: 'test :  912283', //No I18N
        x: -100
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'tests : 75.38%', //No I18N
        align: 'right', //No I18N
        x: -500,
        y: 170
    }
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/t98L5w7s/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` and for example refer to the first point position and dimensions to add the text to the right place:

```
chart: {
    type: 'funnel', //No I18N
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var point = this.series[0].points[0].graphic.getBBox();

            this.renderer.text('test : 912283', point.x + this.plotLeft + point.width / 2, point.y + this.plotTop)
                .attr({
                    align: 'center',
                    zIndex: 3
                })
                .css({
                    color: '#4572A7',
                    fontSize: '16px'
                })
                .add();

            this.renderer.text('tests : 75.28%', point.x + this.plotLeft, point.y + this.plotTop + point.height / 2)
                .attr({
                    align: 'right',
                    zIndex: 3
                })
                .css({
                    color: '#4572A7',
                    fontSize: '12px'
                })
                .add();
        }
    }
}
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c578ay0x/

Comment: thanks, that's working.need one more help ,i need  additional text at the  bottom of funnel high charts. and the top value (test) need to align little more top.

Comment: Hi San in FC, You just need to add another text element with right coordinates: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/43yn9g5L/

Comment: thanks ppotaczek, its working.