# Set equal height for funnel highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to HighCharts. I have created a funnel with the below script

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'funnel'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sales funnel'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                softConnector: true,
                inside: true,
            },
            neckHeight: "0%",
                neckWidth: "80%",
                width: '15%',
                reversed: true,
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Unique users',
        data: [
            ['Website visits', 15654],
            ['Downloads', 4064],
            ['Requested price list', 1987],
            ['Invoice sent', 976],
            ['Finalized', 846]
        ]
    }]
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kiranuk/bavLxzrp/

How can I set equal heights for all the sections?.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A height of a section is calculated based on data. If you want to have equal sections, you can provide mocked equal data and show the real data in a tooltip and data-labels. For example:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.realY:,.0f})',
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return this.series.name + '<br><span style="color:' + this.color + '">●</span> ' + this.point.name + ': <b>' + this.point.realY + '</b>';
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Unique users',
    keys: ['name', 'y', 'realY'],
    data: [
      ['Website visits', 1, 15654],
      ['Downloads', 1, 4064],
      ['Requested price list', 1, 1987],
      ['Invoice sent', 1, 976],
      ['Finalized', 1, 846]
    ]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e4b5o16d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.funnel.data

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have one more question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72215705/how-to-add-text-on-every-section-edges-in-funnel-highcharts

Please look it once.

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309548/how-to-add-text-in-top-left-and-bottom-in-funnel-highcharts